# header fixed breaks fancybox :(

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

This is really weird and can't seem to understand it.  I have a header fixed position so it always stays at top of the screen and for some reason this is causing fancybox not to open..here's my code:

css

```
 #header{background:#fff; width:100%; height:80px; margin:0; padding:0; position:fixed; top:0;}
```

fancybox jquery(latest version 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="img/logo.png" align="left" alt="CSL Peru" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
    <!--end HEADER-->
<div id="container">
         <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">Youtube (iframe)</a>
    </div>
```

when i take "position:fixed" out then it works again but breaks my whole design..

Comment: Oh man awesome! how do I mark this as answered giving you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in Firebug to the actual code when the fancybox gets appended. It might add a `#header` id to one of its wrappers as well

Comment: Really? `#header` is quite common and a plugin shouldn't use it.

Comment: thats what I thought too luckily I speak spanish so I just put "cabecera" lol

Comment: Sorry but disagree. Fancybox doesn't add any wrapper with the ID #header. All fancybox wrappers use the prefix "fancybox" like #fancybox-outer, #fancybox-iframe, etc. This looks more like a css issue than a fancybox issue.

Comment: @JFK If that solved the issue what can it be? How do you know what "fancybox" script used in the code (I'm aware of the one that's really the Fancybox, but the OP could use 'fancybox' just as a common name for that kind of scripts). It might be even a custom written by his buddy, that actually adds `#header` :)

Comment: @ZoltanToth this is definitively a CSS conflict issue but not created by fancybox, which doesn't append any #header to the DOM. If Andres shares a link with a sample of the issue, I could tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @JFK with a link it's easy :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old now, but the problem still occurred to me at the time of this writing, with Fancybox version 2.1.5.

There is a css * selector wich applies a class on all fixed elements.

At line 1833 in jquery.fancybox.js you'll find this code:

```
$('*').filter(function(){
                    return ($(this).css('position') === 'fixed' && !$(this).hasClass("fancybox-overlay") && !$(this).hasClass("fancybox-wrap") );
                }).addClass('fancybox-margin');
```

Comment out these lines and your layout should be ok.